# FlowFiles stuck in the queue in NiFi Cluster

Tags: queue, apache-nifi

I am currently running NiFi 1.9.2 in a clustered environment with 3 nodes. Recently what I have noticed is that the flow seems to get stuck. The queue shows that there are items in the queue, but nothing is going to the downstream processor. When I list the items in the queue, I get "The queue has no FlowFiles".

The queue in this case is set to load balance with round robin. If I stop the downstream processor, and change the configuration on the queue to not to load balance, and then switch it back to round robin again, the queue items distribute to the other two nodes, and I can see the flow files when I list the items in the queue. However, it only shows items as being in two of the nodes. When I restart the downstream processor, the 2/3 of the items get processed leaving the 1/3 that would be on the node whose queue items I cannot see. This behavior seems to persist even after restarting the cluster service.

If I change the queue to not to load balance, then everything seems to get put on a good node, and the queue get emptied. So it looks like there might be something not correct on my first node.

[image: flow with stuck queue]

[image: empty queue?]

Any suggestions on what to try?

Thanks,

-tj

Comment: Can you take a couple of thread dumps while NiFi is in this state? You can run "bin/nifi.sh dump dump1.txt", take 2 or 3 of them and then post the files somewhere

Comment: SharepointFileMetadata - is it a custom processor?

Comment: Yeah, it is a custom processor.

Answer (score 1):

You should check disk usages. If usage rate of the disk nifi located is equal or higher than the "nifi.content.repository.archive.max.usage.percentage" setting in nifi.properties file, you may see this NiFi's strange behavior. If you have this kind of situation, you can try to delete old log files of NiFi